# What does RMSE points about performance of a model in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, performance

I am working on `Decision Tree` algorithm and at the end I calculate `RMSE` value based on actual labels and predicted values (for regression). Now what I am having difficulty in is in understanding the significance of the `RMSE` value that I get. I know that the lower the `RMSE` better is the performance of the model but what `RMSE` value is considered reasonable low or high? Suppose my `RMSE` value comes as `20` so does that mean the performance of my model is `80%` (means 80% of predictions are correct)?

Comment: A [similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56302/84191)

Comment: SO, Standard deviation of what? Observed value or Predicted value?

Answer (score 3):

The root-mean-square error (RMSE) is a frequently used measure of the differences between values (sample and population values) predicted by a model and the values actually observed. The RMSE for your training and your test sets should be very similar if you have built a good model. If the RMSE for the test set is much higher than that of the training set, it is likely that you've badly over fit the data.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple factors to consider, but the first thing to realize is that in regression, you don't want to think about whether an example is "correct" or "incorrect" but rather how close it was to the true target value.  Therefore you can ignore your original intuition about "80% of predictions are 'correct'."

Second remember that [RMSE](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/RootMeanSquaredError) is in the same space as your target values.  So it is relative to the variance in your target values.  The benchmark of random guessing should get you an `RMSE = standard_deviation`.  So lower than this, your model is demonstrating some ability to learn; above that number, you haven't even learned to guess the mean correctly.

There isn't a cutoff for "my model is doing well" in RMSE space, just like with other metrics.  Everything is relative to a naive solution/benchmark or the state-of-the-art.

Comment: So in order to check if my RMSE is good or bad, I can compare it with the standard_deviation to get a rough idea? The standard_deviation should be calculated in actual label values? How can I calculate the standard_deviation?

Comment: Depends on the package you're using, but I'm certain every toolkit for ML will have an easy stdev function. It's also easy to calculate yourself. Basically the StDev is a rough idea of if you're learning anything at all. If you want a better idea, compare to other models.